# Join csv file with a table sql developer read only db

Tags: oracle, csv

I have an excel spreadsheet which has some data, I want to essentially join that with a table in the prod db to which I have only read only access.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Since I can't actually create a table and actually join, I was wondering if there is a way sql developer can store the data in memory.
I'm trying to describe a virtual table.

Specifically I'm working with SQL developer and an Oracle DB. If there are other free tools which support this, then I'm happy to use them too.

Comment: Though there are tools for this, as a programmer we could write down a procedure that reads the file and loads the data into table

Comment: I usually do it by a WITH clause, and a lot of UNION; it needs a bit of text editing and can be very slow, depending on the size of your file. I never found anything better, hope someone can help